# Github profile or repo card on websites made on Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

How to set up/embed github profile or github repository cards on your Jekyll personal website?

I am expecting to embed my personal projects from github in the form of widgets on my personal website.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a direct way to include data in static Jekyll HTML files.

But there are options:

- GitHub offers a [JSON API for repos](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repositories-for-a-user) and [users](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-user). Not sure what profile information you're looking for.
- Jekyll has [data files in YAML](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) where you can store this data and read information from.

My initial idea is to get data in JSON and convert it to YAML, manually or programmatically. Then, you can build a Jekyll site that reads the information from the YAML files.

You can try out the manual way:

- Read data from https://api.github.com/users/cadamini/repos using https://reqbin.com/
- Convert the resulting JSON file using https://www.json2yaml.com/

Put the resulting YAML file in your Jekyll instance, e.g in _data/github/repos.yml (exclude the hyphens).

Extract:

```
- id: 540417594
  node_id: R_kgDOIDYeOg
  name: add-theme-github-pages-demo
  full_name: cadamini/add-theme-github-pages-demo
  private: false
```

Use the following code/syntax to access the information:

```
{% for item in data.github.repos %}
  {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```